# Error al agregar libreria android

Tags: android

Estoy tratando de implementar la librería 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0' pero no me funciona. Android Studio no me reconoce la librería y me da error.
Alguien me podria ayudar por favor.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jamyder.infamperusac"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

[image]

Comment: "*no me funciona*" me parece una descripción insuficiente de tu problema. ¿Podrías dar más detalles?

Comment: Qué error te da?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un proyecto generado con Androidx así que debes usar librerías de androidx.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jamyder.infamperusac"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def recyclerview_version = "1.0.0"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recyclerview_version"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:$recyclerview_version"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La dependencia adecuada que debes definir en tu archivo `build.gradle` debe ser:

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
//implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

Debes cambiar  también el paquete de la clase `RecyclerView` a usar en tu layout,  en lugar de

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

debes de definir la clase RecyclerView de esta forma:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```